# How to map(reference) identical data but different PK?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm doing some database data migration.

The problem is the records (*ContactsID*) has changed - because of PK increment as well as mixed data (I can't just put the SQL result next to each other etc...)

Here is an example

**Data in Original table**

```
+-----------+-------------+
| CompanyID | CompanyName |
+-----------+-------------+
| 1         | Facebook    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

In New Database

```
+-----------+-------------+
| CompanyID | CompanyName |
+-----------+-------------+
| 9         | Facebook    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I'm having issues when it comes to importing matching records from another table that reference the Data in the original database.

Is there a tool I can use to help me match the records?

Here is my desired result

```
+-----------+-------------+-----+
| CompanyID | CompanyName | Key |
+-----------+-------------+-----+
| 1         | Facebook    | 9   |
+-----------+-------------+-----+
```

I will use the **key** import better.

Comment: what do you need? a tool or a script?

Comment: a tool, a sql script will 'ignores' to check the data difference

Answer (score 0):

There is `join`:

```
select o.CompanyName, o.CompanyID, n.CompanyID
from original o join
     newdatabase n
     on o.CompanyName = n.CompanyName
```